# Heat-n-Glo fire place turns itself on

Tags: remote-control

My gas fireplace is a Heat-n-Glow & it turned itself on. The pilot lights fine & doesn't seem to be any other problem.
I normally turn it on with a remote - could bad batteries be causing it to light on its own?

Comment: Is there a thermostat that controls it?

Answer (score 6):

Unbelievable. The instructions say "Caution: Disconnect remote controls if you are absent for extended time periods.  This will prevent accidental fireplace operation." Evidently, Heat-n-Glow is aware of this problem.

The remote obviously uses radio transmission. This creates the possibility that a foreign signal could be misunderstood as your signal. The possibility that your neighbors garage door opener could cause your fireplace to turn on is dependent upon the quality of design and build of the remote control system designed into your fireplace.

Evidently, Heat-n-Glow designed a fireplace which is susceptible to misreading general noise in the air which can cause the fireplace to turn on 'randomly'.

I would not like that at all. I am glad you asked about it. I will try to remember NOT to purchase a Heat-n-Glow fireplace because my garage door remote, or my blue tooth stereo, of my WiFi system or whatever it my be that is not my fireplace remote control causing my fireplace to turn on is what I call a 'serious problem'.

I am not certain that the disclaimer included in the manual would be enough to save Heat-n-Glow from a lawsuit in the event that the problem burned your house down. I would contact Heat-n-Glow and ask them just how it is that you are supposed to 'disconnect the remote controls' every time you leave the house as per the instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.     Fireplace turns on at random times without anyone is this house using any type of transmitter.  To prevent this, I leave the glass panel off, and manually control the remote instrument in the exposed bottom.     When this remote instrument  is on OFF,  then the problem will not occur.   There should be an easy way to control the transmitter frequency.   You change the frequency to another settings until you have found one that is not influenced by outside transmitters.